# iframe get var disappears after request

Tags: html, iframe, get

In an iframe the anchor tag href shows

> http://slideshopro.com/dunlap-hall-entry-tower/?canvasObject=4&exportId=53d0049571034

after the request is processed the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] shows

> http://slideshopro.com/dunlap-hall-entry-tower/?exportId=53d0049571034

The first get var is disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

The get is not disappearing. It shows with request uri, instead of http_referer